# How to make same script work for all the Tabs in a spreadsheet (Google Apps Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script

My Googlesheet have multiple sheets, and I don't want this script to apply to the whole spreadsheet, if I write one script for each sheet, the script editor would reach 1000 lines.

```
function onEdit(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName1");
  var num= sheet.getRange("N30").getValue();
  if((num%4)>2)
 {
    num = ((Math.floor((num/4))) + 1)*4;
  }
 else
 {
    num = Math.floor((num/4))*4;
  }
  sheet.getRange("N30").setValue(num);
}
```

How can I make the same script work for multiple sheets (with different SheetNames) inside a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit()
{ 
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var totalSheets = sheets.length;

  for(var i=0;i<totalSheets;i++)
  {
    var num= sheets[i].getRange("N30").getValue();
    if((num%4)>2)
    {
      num = ((Math.floor((num/4))) + 1)*4;
    }
    else
    {
      num = Math.floor((num/4))*4;
    }

    sheets[i].getRange("N30").setValue(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm a script newbie, I've already searched this question in Google, but not sucess. What code format should I follow to define the sheets length. Example. My spreadsheet have 10 sheets, I want this script apply to sheet 4 to 10, but excluding sheet 1 to 3.

Comment: The above code will work for all 10 sheets. If you want to exclude the first 3 sheets then replace the line `for(var i=0;i<totalSheets;i++)` by `for(var i=3;i<totalSheets;i++)`

Comment: Dude you are a godsend. :)